# Is there a crazyhouse+bughouse chess variant?

Tags: chess-variants

I would like to know if the following chess variant or a closely related one exists.

There are 4 players, say 1 to 4. Players 1 and 2 form a team and play aginst players 3 & 4 team. Player 1 plays against player 3, and player 2 against player 4. Players in 1st team play white on both boards. Both teams have a common pool of pieces, which are initially empty. At his turn, a player from team X can either make a normal chess move or take a piece from the pool of team X and drop it on an empty square (of course, it is removed from the pool).  Pawns may not be dropped on the first or eighth ranks. Whenever a player from team X makes a capture, the captured piece changes colour and is added to the pool of team X. A team wins when one of their opponents is checkmated or runs out of time.

PS: If this is new, what would be a nice name? The names nuthouse chess, mad chess, crazy chess, etc. are taken! How about *bro chess*?

Comment: I suppose "double crazyhouse" would be the sanest possible name.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq  How about "team crazyhouse"? I thougt, may be, we have to forget the names crazyhouse and bughouse to come up with a cool name.